# Using Firebase Analytics and Google Analytics together - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, firebase, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics (FA) and Google Analytics (GA) together in my iOS app. We can achieve that using Google Tag Manager.

I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/#introduction

I setup Google Tag Manager Triggers and Tags correctly. I have chosen "GoogleAnalytics" as the product which is asking when setting the Tag in Google Tag Manager. I assume that, when I fire events using fire base analytics, the same events should appear in google analytics too. It doesn't seem to be working for me. I do see FA dashboard being updated but nothing is showing up in GA.

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"BtnPressed" parameters:nil];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

A few things to check: Did you set up the appropriate triggers for the event? Did you publish your Google Tag Manager container? Is the container file included in a container folder (not a group), and included in the binary?

Another thing to keep in mind is that it can take some time for Google Analytics events to show up. One way of checking your configuration is to run in the simulator, which will cause Google Tag Manager to log verbosely. If everything is configured correctly, you'll see log messages from Google Tag Manager when you log an event. If there's a configuration problem, you should see log messages indicating an issue.

Comment: This was answered in more detail at https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/XApLcLZ-258;context-place=forum/tag-manager